# Answering with a code snippet vs answering just with indications

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

A user asks something like:

> I'm new to Java and I need to change JTextField to int[] array.

He gets two answers:

1. A code snippet solving his problem.
2. A written answer indicating what methods to use and inviting/forcing him/her to create his/her own code.

Probably, the accepted answer would be the one that makes his/her life easier (the first one), and the second one would be something like the perfect way to miss out an accept.

So, if you really think the second one is a better answer for a newbie, would you keep posting it?

Comment: First I would edit that question and remove the "I'm new to Java" part because it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Good point ;o) But after that? Post a comment asking if he/she is new to SO?

Answer (score 7):

I personally think the second answer is better. Yes, the first answer is usually accepted, and this makes sense -- it is the one that helped the OP solve his problem the most.

I don't really find anything wrong with that, the acceptance tick isn't something to fret over.

Usually the types of people who want an elaborate, conceptual answers are the same types of people who will not stop scrolling after reading the first answer. As long as your answer is useful to some people, I'd suggest that you post it. I would.

Even better would be doing both :)

Answer (score 6):

### I prefer code with explanation :)

I think that there's a reason that code-only snippets show up in the very low quality review queue - but I'm not sure what to do with them. Delete them? No, they are helpful.

What would make them better?

A little bit of explanation.

With that in mind, many people that answer questions here want the rep. While it seems that just giving a code snippet gets rep easier, often just a little bit of explanation gets far more.

I ask questions here. I absolutely *hate* when someone answers with something like:

> Just foo the bar on the baz and you'll be fine.

When all they need to do is add a code snippet:

> Just foo the bar on the baz and you'll be fine.
>
> `[baz.bar foo]`

Ultimately, I would go for code with just a little explanation. If I had to choose, however, I would go for the one that helps the most:

### Code sample.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would be the `foo.bar` receiving the `baz` message.

Comment: @Cole Objective-C

Comment: I know. I was making a joking remark. It's not to easy to convey emotion over the Internet.